# How to send an Ethernet frame with Php without protocol (IP/UDP/TCP...)

Tags: php

I'm using a PHP server to manage a platform composed of computers and devices.

But a new one (device) hasn't implemented protocol layer above the MAC layer.
Eventually, i shall use custom format to communicate with it. Here it is :
MAC header - 46 raw data - MAC CRC

I think socket would be a good idea but i didn't understand how ?
Here is my function:

```
<?php
function request_data($str)
{
    $create=socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_RAW,1);
    $send=socket_send($create,$str,strlen($str),0);
    socket_close($create);
}
?>
```

Could you help me ?

Comment: As far as I know you can't, a protocol is a basic requirement for a networked device to communicate with *other* devices on the network. I'm sure what you're proposing is impossible.

Comment: You're going to need a lot more than just PHP code for this, if the remote device doesn't support TCP/IP

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know that pcap library for C language for example manage this kind of function. I thought RAW data for PHP mean "without protocol".

Comment: SOCK_RAW will use IP (but neither TCP nor UDP above it)

Answer (score 0):

AF_INET already declares that this is uses IP protocol, so you can't MAC protocol fields.
Your ethernet device may already have a library to send raw packets, which you need to use.  If it doesn't, you wont be able send raw packets from PHP

Answer (score 0):

**Thanks to all** for your explanation.

Indeed, i looked for another kind of solution and I've found a way to send/receive some frame without protocol:
in c/c++, a library named "libpcap" have been designed for this kind of stuff.
Using "[swig](http://www.swig.org/)", one can extract some functions (with an interface file for adaptation) and generate a php extension (*.so).
Look for "[**marcelog**](http://marcelog.github.io/articles/swig_php_libpcap_module_c++.html)" on the web. He has published an article with an example about this.
I have nearly validated the solution on my configuration : apache2 with php5 on Ubuntu 14.04 64bits.

**BUT**, I have a last "linux" problem of permission.
I can't do the following king of command

```
$ php -c php.ini inject.php eth0 "" 4096 10000 myRawPacketData.raw
```

*- php.ini contains the link where is the extension, 
- inject.php contains the script which use a libpcap function
- eth0 (parameter 1) is the interface on my computer
- "" (parameter 2) is a filter
- 4096 (parameter 3) is the lenght
- 10000 (parameter 4) is the timeout
- myRawPacketData.raw (parameter 5) contains the data to send*

I have the following error :

> *what():  Could not open device: eth0: eth0: You don't have permission to capture on that device (socket: Operation not permitted) Abandon
>   (core dumped)*

But a can do:

```
$ **sudo** php -c php.ini inject.php eth0 "" 4096 10000 myRawPacketData.raw
```

It sends a frame on my interface (confirmed by wireshark).
For information, i did this command, because eth0 wasn't available in wireshark:

```
sudo chmod 4711 'sudo which dumpcap'
```

Could you help me to auth apache2(or wwww-data) to access eth0 without the sudo command because currently, i can't use inject.php script outside the console (and this is not my goal) ?